# Configuring custom pivot tables in QGIS for QField

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, qfield

I have the form setup, however I would like to configure some questions further so that capturing data is easier and with minimal error. Currently I can capture the information manually however, its tedious and one can easily make mistake. I would like to have the table below, where I can input the number of the people. Is this durable with html widgets? Hints?

**Current Qfield form customization**
[image]

**Desired table in qfield**

[image]